# Fill an array with random characters chosen from a list without duplicates

Tags: objective-c, arrays, char, switch-statement

I am trying to fill an array with 4 of 6 different characters where each character in the array is different. The character  that is placed into the array is based on a switch statement. Then I want to go back through the array to make sure the character I just placed is not already in the array and if it is I have to put in a different character. How do I do this? I don't want to refill the whole array, just this one spot.

This is the code I have so far, comments included:

```
-(void) fillarray{

for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    int randomNum = arc4random() % 6; // generates a random number

          switch (randomNum) // based on the number generated, it choses what color will be placed into the slot
    {
        case 1:
            colorarray[i] ='r';
            break;

        case 2:
            colorarray[i] ='o';
            break;

        case 3:
            colorarray[i] ='y';
            break;

        case 4:
            colorarray[i] ='g';
            break;
        case 5:
            colorarray[i] = 'b';

        case 6:
            colorarray[i] = 'p';

        default:
            break;
    }

    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) // runs through the array to ensure that the recently placed color does not match previous placed colors
    {
        while (j /= i)

            if (colorarray[i]==colorarray[j]) // if the color is already in the array
                                            //try again to place another color in this location

    }
```

Comment: If you want really easy uniquing, use an NSSet. NSSet will remove any non-unique objects contained in it.

Comment: anyway, I wouldn't worry about the uniquing part of the problem. I added a solution that just shuffles the choices and chooses the first _n_ items from that.

Answer (score 1):

First you take an array (you can also use NSArray, here I suppose you want to use C-style arrays) of all the possibile characters that you cane extract:

```
char characters[]={'r','o','y','g','b','p'};
int length=6;
```

Then every time you extract a character you decrease the length variable and swap the last character extracted with the last one, to make sure that it won't be used again:

```
int randomNum = arc4random() % length;
< put characters[randomNum] somewhere>
char temp=characters[randomNum];
characters[randomNum]=characters[length-1];
characters[length-1]=temp;
length--;
```

PS: The % operand returns the remainder of the quotient, so a number % N will never be N, it's range goes from 0 to N-1.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this, based on the [Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_.22inside-out.22_algorithm)

```
NSArray * array = @[ @"r", @"o", @"y", @"g", @"b", @"p" ] ;
array = [ [ array shuffledArray ] subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){ .length = 4 } ] ;
```

Where `-shuffledArray` is added to NSArray by:

```
@implementation NSArray ( Shuffling )

-(NSArray*)shuffledArray
{
    NSMutableArray * result = [ NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.count ] ;
    [ result addObject:self[0] ] ;
    for( NSUInteger index=1, count = self.count; index < count; ++index )
    {
        int j = arc4random_uniform( (unsigned int)index ) ;
        [ result addObject:result[j] ] ;
        [ result replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:self[ index ] ] ;
    }

    return result ;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

the function should look like this:

```
    int found = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        while(found) {
           int randomNum = arc4random() % 6;
           switch (randomNum) 
           {
              case 1:
                colorarray[i] ='r';
                break;

              case 2:
                colorarray[i] ='o';
                break;

             case 3:
               colorarray[i] ='y';
               break;

             case 4:
               colorarray[i] ='g';
               break;
             case 5:
               colorarray[i] = 'b';
               break;

             case 6:
               colorarray[i] = 'p';

             default:
               break;
           }
           found = 0;
           for (int j = i-1; i >= 0; j--) {
              if (colorarray[i] == colorarray[j])
                 found = 1;
           }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't want to use switch or (essentially) remove the character you received from the array by decrementing a length variable, you could always do this:

```
char colorarray[5] = {0,0,0,0,'\0'};
char possibleCharacters[6] = {'r', 'o', 'y', 'g', 'b', 'p'};
BOOL isNotUnique = NO;

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    do{
        colorarray[i] = possibleCharacters[arc4random() % 6];
        for(int j = i - 1; j > -1; --j){
            if(colorarray[i] == colorarray[j]){
                isNotUnique = YES;
                break;
            }
            else isNotUnique = NO;
        }
    }while(isNotUnique);
}

NSLog(@"%s", colorarray);
```

The actual loop for getting the characters basically reads:

```
1    for each spot in the colors arrays
2        generate a random number and use it to get a character
3        check to see if the character is identical to any spot before this one
4        if our new character matched any previous one, repeat from 2 on
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to shuffle an array (to get the top X elements which will be random). Basically you do what Ramy Alzury and nielsbot responded. The algorithm goes like this.

```
Do this 10 times the length of the array
    swap the last element with a random element chosen from the array
```

At the end this should yield a randomly shuffled array (you are shuffling it 10 times)

Here's a sample function in Objective C.

```
-(NSArray *) shuffleArray:(NSArray *) arr{
    NSMutableArray * mArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.count*10;i++){
        int num = arc4random()%arr.count;
        NSString * temp = (NSString *)[mArr objectAtIndex:arr.count-1];
        [mArr replaceObjectAtIndex: arr.count-1 withObject:[mArr objectAtIndex:num]]; 
        [mArr replaceObjectAtIndex:num withObject:temp];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:mArr];
}
```