# unable to create unique array of NSNumber - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I read on some SO thread on making an unique array, unfortunately, it did not work for me.

BackGround Info -

- I have an objectArray filled with 20 object in it.
- a NSObject sampleData with a field NSNumber * number;
- maxCount is a int which user input how many random numbers they want.
- below is my code in Xcode and the return for calling the function

.m

```
-(IBAction) testButton
{
[self chooseNumber];
}

-(void)chooseNumber
{
    maxCount = [numberOfClues.text intValue];
   // NSInteger rdmNumber = arc4random()%objectArray.count;

    int count = 0;
    do {

        NSInteger rdmNumber = arc4random()%objectArray.count;
        if (![dataArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rdmNumber]])
        {
            currentData.number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rdmNumber];
            [dataArray addObject:currentData];
            currentData=nil;
            currentData= [[sampleData alloc]init];
            count++;    
            NSLog(@"random no - %d",rdmNumber);
        }
    } while (count < maxCount);
    NSLog(@"Array got %d numbers",dataArray.count);
}
```

return value from NSLog

```
2012-11-29 08:26:50.888 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 5
2012-11-29 08:26:50.892 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 8
2012-11-29 08:26:50.926 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 5
2012-11-29 08:26:50.930 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 10
2012-11-29 08:26:50.933 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 4
2012-11-29 08:26:50.946 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 10
2012-11-29 08:26:50.949 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 9
2012-11-29 08:26:50.952 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 12
2012-11-29 08:26:50.955 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 0
2012-11-29 08:26:50.957 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 15
2012-11-29 08:26:50.960 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 1
2012-11-29 08:26:50.963 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 8
2012-11-29 08:26:50.964 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 18
2012-11-29 08:26:50.966 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 14
2012-11-29 08:26:50.968 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 12
2012-11-29 08:26:50.977 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 14
2012-11-29 08:26:50.980 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 3
2012-11-29 08:26:50.983 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 6
2012-11-29 08:26:50.986 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 15
2012-11-29 08:26:50.989 randomNumbers[1255:11303] random no - 7
2012-11-29 08:26:50.992 randomNumbers[1255:11303] Array got 20 numbers
```

How do I make it such that the array will get all unique number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill an array with random characters chosen from a list without duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646168/fill-an-array-with-random-characters-chosen-from-a-list-without-duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here

```
if (![dataArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rdmNumber]]) {
     currentData.number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rdmNumber];
     [dataArray addObject:currentData];
```

You are checking for `NSNumber` instances but you don't put `NSNumber` inside the array, you are putting something completely different (`currentData`).

If you need both ordering (do you really need ordering?) and uniqueness, a combination of `NSArray` and `NSSet` can be used for effectiveness. Of course, this is more effective only if you do lots of operations which needs the uniqueness check. If you only want to create an array and and use it without changes, your implementation (using `[NSArray containsObject:]` will be better.
Abstracting everything into a special class is always a good solution:

```
@interface UniqueArray

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray* elements;

- (BOOL)addObject:(id)object;

@end
```

```
@interface UniqueArray ()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSArray* elements;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSMutableSet* set;

@end

@implementation UniqueArray

- (id)init {
   self = [super init];

   if (!self) {
      return nil;
   }

   self.elements = [NSMutableArray array];
   self.set = [NSMutableSet set];

   return self;
}

- (BOOL)addObject:(id)object {
   if ([self.set containsObject:object]) {
      return NO;
   }

   [self.set addObject:object];
   [(NSMutableArray*) self.elements addObject:object];

   return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand what you meant. Even though the class property has `NSNumber`, what it added was the `object` and not the `NSNumber` field, so `containObject` will not be able to define `NSNumber` since it's all `object`. Am I right about it?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need an array? Why not use an NSMutableSet?

[From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html):

> The NSMutableSet class declares the programmatic interface to a
>   mutable, unordered collection of distinct objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has been asked before. You can fill the array with numbers 1 to 20, shuffle the array, then choose the first (n) numbers from the shuffled array.

I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12649065/210171

Comment: Ah yes, that would have solved my problem as well. It's just that I have a previous function in c# that is working already, so I just thought of replicating it into Xcode rather than thinking of another way to my function.