# Printing Random values in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

So I'm playing around with a few WatchKit ideas in swift, and decided to make a random playing card generator. The attached image shows my code and the output I get when I run the "shuffle" function. Notice how the output seems to place 2 values together, add random number values in from seemingly nowhere, and it even also displayed a 12 of spades option, even though there is no entry for "12" in the values array.

I'm new to programming and am doing this just to play around with a few ideas and get grasps of swift. So could anyone help me to understand why this is happening and how to prevent it?

Many thanks in advance guys.[image: Code for the shuffle method as well as output when the function is called]

Comment: It would be very helpful if you post your code in text format rather than as a screenshot - images can help, but they cannot be copied and pasted in an editor :)

Comment: Eoin, when you say "it even also displayed a 12 of spades option"...I'm not seeing a 12 in the console, in your screenshot. Could you explain that a little more?

Comment: Yeah sure, it wasn't showing it in this particular case. But it randomly generates 52 different outputs each time as that is the purpose of the method. It didn't show the 12 of spades in this instance of running the method but it did previously.

Comment: Please post your code in order for us to help you. It is hard to work with a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating the deck first then shuffling it.  Something like:

```
var deck = [String]()
for value in values {
    for suite in suites {
        deck.append(value+suite)
    }
 }

var shuffledDeck = [String]()
for i in 0..<52 {
    let seed = UInt32(deck.count - 1)
    let randomCardIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(seed))
    shuffledDeck.append(deck.removeAtIndex(randomCardIndex))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Jeremy Pope's answer and one of my [old answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12649065/210171) here's a playground that shows how to shuffle 52 random objects.

```
import Foundation

extension Array
{
    func shuffled() -> Array
    {
        var result:Array = []

        result.append( self[0] )

        for index in 0..<self.count
        {
            let j = Int( arc4random_uniform( UInt32( index ) ) )
            result.append( result[ j ] )
            result[ j ] = self[ index ]
        }

        return result ;
    }
}

let suits = ["♠️", "♥️", "♣️", "♦️"]
let ranks = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
var stringArray = Array(0...51).map { number in
    "\(suits[number / 13])\(ranks[number % 13])"
}
stringArray = stringArray.shuffled()
```

result:

> [♥️8, ♣️7, ♠️4, ♦️J, ♦️10, ♦️7, ♠️A, ♠️9, ♥️A, ♥️7, ♦️4, ♠️8, ♠️A,
>   ♦️A, ♠️2, ♠️3, ♣️6, ♣️2, ♣️A, ♥️5, ♥️K, ♣️10, ♦️3, ♥️3, ♥️2, ♠️6, ♣️J,
>   ♠️10, ♥️9, ♦️5, ♠️5, ♠️7, ♦️9, ♣️4, ♣️Q, ♣️8, ♠️K, ♦️6, ♥️J, ♣️5, ♠️J,
>   ♣️9, ♦️8, ♥️4, ♥️10, ♥️Q, ♦️2, ♦️Q, ♦️K, ♣️3, ♥️6, ♠️Q, ♣️K]